# Handling a form with multiple actions

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm trying to make a form that creates a new post in my wordpress site, upload a video to my Bits on the run account, and retrieves this video url.

As stated [here](http://www.longtailvideo.com/support/bits-on-the-run/15984/upload-videos-within-your-cms) I have to set the form action to a url for the api to work, but I have to handle other form inputs using a php file.

SO is there a way I can use multiple actions for the form?

Comment: You cannot have multiple actions for an HTML form, but you can upload the video to your server, and use cURL etc to `upload a video to my Bits on the run account, and retrieves this video url.`

Comment: DaveRandom is completely right. You need to submit to a PHP form on your own site, then use cURL to interact with Bits On The Run.

Answer (score 0):

You could set the form to submit to a php page, and on that page (depending on whether your method="post" or method="get") you can use the variable attained to do whatever you'd like.

Answer (score 0):

You can submit each form into ONLY one URL, I suggest to write a script (e.g. a PHP script) & after submit your form to that script, you can forward your request to other APIs.